# How does 'cmp' command works?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have assembly class at my university and having trouble understanding some of the basic operations (i'v missed couple of classes in the beginning).

I have a simple program that prints a number, this is the program:

```
.model  small
.stack   100h
.data

num  dw  -32768
numS db  6 dup(' '),'$'

.code
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, num
    mov bx, 10

    mov si, offset numS+5

next:
    cwd
    idiv    bx
    cmp dx, 0
    jge cont
    neg dx

cont:
    add dl, 48
    mov [si],   dl
    dec si
    cmp ax, 0
    jz  sof
    jmp next

sof:    
    cmp num,    0
    jge soff
    mov byte ptr[si],   '-'

soff:
    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, si
    int 21h
    .exit

end
```

I checked in other website what is the cmp command is doing and the actual algo is opr1 - opr2...so in this program i take the reminder of the devision (ax/bx which placed in dx) and decrement zero from it..? I dont understand how is the comparison works here.. :/

Please help me understand it, im a complete beginner here and im stuck..

If someone doesn't mind to explain this program in general and give extra focus to the comparison that would be awesome..

cheers

Comment: There are many different assembly languages, which one specifically are you working with (what is the type of chip your code will run on eventually, a x86 processor or a embedded system like a HC11)?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain we are working with 80x86 processor

Comment: is this too hard to google? You don't even need to read Intel manual to get `cmp` functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cmp` performs exactly the same operation that `sub` performs, BUT it does NOT save the result in the destination register. However, just like `sub`, it sets the flag registers which can be using in a subsequent conditional jump operation.